# Pytest: Wrapping every test in try/except

Tags: python-3.x, selenium, pytest, selenium-grid

I'm trying to troubleshoot annoying sporadic selenium grid disconnect errors, like this:

```
http.client.RemoteDisconnected: Remote end closed connection without response
```

in my tests that use the pytest framework.  I'd like to be able to catch in a try/except a specific error (like the one above), so that I can add the name of the method that's failing to the printed output (currently, the stack trace does not include it).  I'm not sure where to do it to wrap every test.

This needs to be in a fixture (I think), since I need the request funcarg so that I can access the request.node.name to get the actual test name.

Any advice?

Comment: Did you find a solution for this?

Comment: Sadly, no. I was able to deduce the name of the failing function for this narrow purpose because I have code that wraps the pytest (.main()) invocation, and so I can parse the stack trace that is printed. But, this is a hack and not ideal.